# How to convert multiple ipynb files (which are in GCP) to py files

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, terraform-provider-gcp, gcp-ai-platform-notebook, gcp-ai-platform-training

Is there any way to convert ipynb files to .py

I have tried file extension change method but unable to execute the (.py) files after conversion.

I also seen a method to convert ipynb files to .py  (nbconvert) but it didnt work.

----> (nbconvert method worked in my local machine)

But i need to perform operation in GCP (files which are stored in my buckets)

Below is the code which i have used to convert ipynb to py. not able to convert by this.

is there any other way?

```
pip install notebooktoall
from notebooktoall.transform import transform_notebook
transform_notebook(ipynb_file=”my_jupyter_notebook.ipynb”, export_list=[“html”, “py”])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Google Cloud Datalab](https://cloud.google.com/datalab/docs/how-to/working-with-notebooks).

Cloud Datalab is built on Jupyter and is a powerful interactive tool created to explore, analyze, transform, and visualize data and build machine learning models on Google Cloud Platform.

Steps to set up and open Cloud Datalab:
First update your gcloud CLI components so you're sure you have the latest version.
`gcloud components update`

After that you can install through the CLI using apt or yum

`sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade google-cloud-sdk`

`sudo yum upgrade google-cloud-sdk`

Install the datalab component

`gcloud components install datalab`

In case you have installed using apt or yum, use these commands to update the components:

`sudo apt update && sudo apt install google-cloud-sdk-datalab`

`sudo yum install google-cloud-sdk-datalab`

Create a datalab instance:

`datalab create datalab-instance-name`

Here is a [link](https://cloud.google.com/datalab/docs/quickstart) to the quickstart tutorials depending on what you need.

Basically Datalab is Google Cloud answer to use in the Google Cloud ecosystem.